# Automatically switch gpu graphics driver when gaming

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, games

I have installed Ubuntu GNOME 15.10. I installed the nvidia tested proprietary driver and then I restarted. Afterr that I selected as primary GPU the Intel driver for normal use.
However, when I enter a steam game(Portal) the graphics is bad so In order to play normal I have to switch manually to the nvidia driver again and reboot again. After the game I have to manually select as primary driver the Intel one and reboot again. It is so boring.
QUESTION: How to automatically switch gpu graphics driver when I enter a game or something that needs more GPU?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it automatically, but here is a work around I thought of.

First open a text editor like `gedit` and paste this in to a new file

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Steam
Comment=Steam with Nvidia
Exec=sudo prime-select nvidia && steam
Icon=/usr/share/app-install/icons/steam.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
```

Now save this as `steam.desktop` to your `/home` and make it executable

```
chmod +x ~/steam.desktop
```

Now drag the file to the launcher to replace the existing Steam icon and when you run Steam from this it should also switch to the Nvidia GPU.

The quickest way to switch back would be to use this command

```
sudo prime-select intel
```

You could create another desktop file to run the command from but if you run it once it will be accessible from the terminals history, by the <kbd>up arrow</kbd> key.

Please note I don't have a multi GPU laptop, so I can't test this, so please do give any feedback.

Comment: So that means no, right? Unless I run the app with the specific arguments.

Comment: Yes, this way will make a new launcher you can just click but you can't make it automatic.