# Does Ubuntu 16.04 automatically switch between gpus?

Tags: 16.04, switchable-graphics

Does Ubuntu 16.04 know how to automatically switch between gpus (if present) with the default open source drivers?

For example running a game on the dedicated card but only using the integrated one for processes that don't require much graphics power.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/741328/automatically-switch-gpu-graphics-driver-when-gaming

Comment: Rinzwind: So that means no, right? Unless I run the app with specific arguments.