# Utilise GPU automatically for applications?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, gpu

I have seen several questions on this forum regarding the GPU drivers or GPU power being utilized for some applications (like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/741328/automatically-switch-gpu-graphics-driver-when-gaming)) but none of them answer my question. As I have switched from Windows to Linux only today, I am a bit unfamiliar with it

> Does Ubuntu automatically utilize GPU for certain applications? If not is there any way to dedicate certain applications to utilize 'High performance' hardware like to GPU to boost themselves?

**BTW**: would there be any single GUI tool to monitor both CPU and GPU (memory too, if possible)?

Comment: If anybody likes the question I posed, and want to know the answer too, could they be so kind as to assign a bounty to it? I am not able to due to lack of repo....